# Can't curl. curl: (7) Failed to connnect... Connection Refused

Tags: curl

I can't curl one of my installed software using the external EC2 ip address but if I curl using localhost:5000 (or 127.0.0.1:5000), it works fine.  Any insights will be appreciated.

I've installed these 3 items:

- Elasticsearch, port 9200        => I can curl using internal and external IP
- Jenkins, port 8080                   => I can curl using internal and external IP
- Python Flask app, port 5000  => I CAN'T curl using external IP. Internal IP works fine

Using the external IP address, I can curl the first two items but not the python flask application.

Here's the error below.  I replaced the real ip address with "external_ip":

```
$ curl -v external_ip:5000
* Rebuilt URL to: external_ip:5000/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying external_ip...
* connect to external_ip port 5000 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to external_ip port 5000: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to external_ip port 5000: Connection refused
```

Here's the curl version:

```
$ curl --version
curl 7.35.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.35.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1f zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 librtmp/2.3
```

Here's the OS version:

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS"
```

netstat shows all ports are being listened to but the port in question is linked to 127.0.0.1.  How can I get this to be mapped to the external ip address?

```
$ sudo netstat -an | grep -E "5000|9200|8080"
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::9200                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

By the way, I ran into the same results using Vagrant.

Any ideas?

Comment: Connection refused generally means nothing is listening on the relevand IP:port pair, we already have [loads of Q&A](http://serverfault.com/search?q=user%3A9517+connection+refused+netstat) about this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flask apps by default only listen on the local interface, if you want your app to be available on external addresses, start it as `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')`

Comment: Thanks.  I tried something with your idea but I'm completely new to the Python world so I'll talk to the developer about it and come back with the results.

Comment: Dennis, after digging around some more, I found the right place to make your changes.  Thanks!  I'm very happy to enter the world of Python.

Comment: Can you say what that place was?

Comment: @sftoparis sudo tell us where the right place was